# $wpdb error cant fix

Tags: select, wordpress

i create custom plugin and i have table wp_customers , i try to select all things in my table but wordpress just show me Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\rflredirection\public\showResult.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\rflredirection\public\showResult.php on line 4

i see codex , i use some antoher codes for select but i just that massege , this is my codes to try

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM $wpd->wp_customers DESC ');
```

and

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_customers');
```

and

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_customers";
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT code FROM ".$table_name");
```

and i try get version but nothing

```
$dbVersion = $wpdb->db_version();
if ($dbVersion) {
    echo "Running MySQL " . $dbVersion;
} else {
    echo "MySQL version unavailable.";
}
```

Comment: $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_customers DESC '); check your and mine syntax. $wpdb not write correctly.

Comment: that my mistack to type here dude , and i change again but
Call to a member function get_results() on null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ***The wpdb Class***, there is no need to include `wp_` in tables name.

*should be just like this:*

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->customers");
//                                                  ^ use without (wp_)
```

**Edit #1:**

you have an error on `foreach` loop:

you should write `foreach($results as $rows)` instead of your error : `foreach($rows as $results)`

and don't forget the semicolons when get values, `echo $rows["id"];` and so on..

your code should like:

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->customers");
?>
<body>
 <table> 
    <tr> 
        <th>‌ID</th>
         <th>Name</th> 
         <th>Family</th>
          <th>Numbers</th> 
          <th>Tell</th> 
      </tr>
       <?php foreach($results as $rows){
        ?> 
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?php echo $rows["name"]; ?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?php echo $rows["family"]; ?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?php echo $rows["numbers"]; ?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <?php echo $rows["tell"]; ?>
            </td>
             <?php }?> 
         </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit #2:**

*Copy **all** this lines and paste on top of your page to include wordpress package:*

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress User Page
 *
 * Handles authentication, registering, resetting passwords, forgot password,
 * and other user handling.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing.
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Now your page codes goes here ...
```

Comment: nothing just : Call to a member function get_results() on null

Comment: this is full code here :
<?php

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->customers");

?>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>‌ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Family</th>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        <th>Tell</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $results){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows["id"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["name"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["family"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["numbers"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows["tell"]?></td>
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: i use thi code var_dump( isset( $wpdb ) ); and send me back bool(false)
it's help ?

Comment: i use it my friend and agin i have  Call to a member function get_results()
and it say error on line 3

Comment: it work in main page , but when i write the code in other page , and make button to click and user go to that page to see them result i give that error

Comment: @pouria Now if it works on main page after correcting, you should include the wordpress package to page your are using if your page is not from wordpress templates. _See my edits2 on answer_

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept this answer if it was helpful to you my friend :) Thanks. @pouria

Comment: tnx alot that is my problm tnx , and for javascripts and css i need to do that ? i mean how can i include my own css and javascript in plugin

Comment: and something else , when i use that code word press tell me cant open strem the file , i use this code $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
why cant open strem simple require ?

Comment: You can add **CSS** and **JS** to page header as usual, for JS: `<script src="your js path"></script>` , for CSS: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your CSS path">`